# Cannot FTP upload using php

Tags: php, ftp

I have this code:

```
<?php

$host = "ftp.myserver.com";
$port = 21;
$username = "my_username";
$password = "my_password";
$destination = "/folder/folder2/test.txt";
$file = __DIR__."/folder/folder2/test.txt";

$connection = ftp_connect($host, $port);
if (!$connection) 
    throw new Exception("Cannot found host");

$login = ftp_login($connection, $username, $password);
if (!$login)
    throw new Exception("Cannot login with provided credentials");

// return mime type ala mimetype extension
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);

//check to see if the mime-type starts with 'text'
$isText = substr(finfo_file($finfo, $file), 0, 4) == 'text';
$mode = $isText == true ? FTP_ASCII : FTP_BINARY;

ftp_pasv($connection, true);

$upload = ftp_put($connection, $destination, $file, $mode);
if (!$upload) {
    echo error_get_last();
}

ftp_close($connection);
```

And when I run via CMD, the result is as follow:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\ftptest>php test.php

Warning: ftp_put(): Can't open that file: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\
htdocs\ftptest\test.php on line 27
Array
```

Line 27 is on `ftp_put` command. Folder `folder` and `folder2` is not exist on ftp server. I expect it created by `ftp_put` (Or should I check and create it manually?)

Comment: have you tried creating it manually to test?  Maybe it'd be worth finding out the commands for creating a new folder and doing that first.  You can't put something someplace where the somplace doesn't exist...if that makes sense

Comment: Check if it exists with `is_dir()`, if not then use `ftp_mkdir()` or `mkdir()`.

Comment: mkdir() - couldn't remember it! nice one @BenFortune

Comment: You could also use `ftp_chdir()` to check, something like `if(!ftp_chdir($con,$dir)){ftp_mkdir($con,$dir);}`

Comment: It is work when folder is created manually. So ftp_put doesn't create the folder. Looks like I have to check/create folder by folder. Or is there another way to create the folder automatically?

Comment: Ahh, I see. Will try that code.